# Find differences between adjacent elements of array

Tags: ruby

I am just wondering if there is a good way (without cycles) to find differences between adjacent elements of array:

```
[2, 8, 12] -> [6, 4]

a(n) = a(n+1) - a(n)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
[2, 8, 12].each_cons(2).map{|a, b| b - a} # => [6, 4]
```

That's still a couple of cycles, but you don't see them.

Answer (score 5):

```
a = [2, 8, 12]
a.map.with_index(1){|e,i| a[i]-e if a[i] }.compact # => [6, 4]
```

**Benchmark**

```
require 'benchmark'

a = (1..10000000).to_a

Benchmark.bm(10) do |b|
  b.report("each_cons") { a.each_cons(2).map{|a, b| b - a} }
  b.report("map_with_index") { a.map.with_index(1){|e,i| a[i]-e if a[i] }.compact }
end
```

**output**

```
                   user     system      total        real
each_cons       38.298000  0.156000  38.454000 ( 38.561856)
map_with_index  1.435000   0.000000   1.435000 (  1.428143)
```

Comment: It's one of those sad occasions where doing it "the right way" (meaning: using the correct abstraction) results in a much slower code. I'd still use `each_cons` though :)

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it. Not as fast as Arup's way but almost:

```
a.zip(a.rotate).map{|x,y|y-x}.tap(&:pop)
```